# Thousand separator in javascript using regular expressions

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using this regular expression to make a textbox allow a number with 6 digits and two decimal places:

```
var regEx = /^\d{0,6}(,\d{0,2})?$/
```

Now, I want to make it allow the same thing but with a thousand separator.
Eg: I want 1321,54 to be 1.321,54.

Thank you.

Comment: The number has six digits left of the decimal (as implied by `\d{0,6}`) or six digits including the two right of the decimal?

Comment: Be aware that the thousand separator depends on the culture; US uses the format `123,456,789.123` while others such as Germany and France use `123.456.789,123`, and then there are also some like Switzerland which use `123'456'789.123`.

Comment: You might want to take a look for locale-aware libraries rather than rolling your own.  Perhaps something like this? http://code.google.com/p/jquery-numberformatter/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you want this?

```
/^(\d{1,3}\.\d{3}|\d{0,6})(,\d{0,2})?$/
```

It just adds the case where the 4, 5 or 6 pre-decimal digits are separated by a dot in the usual place.

Answer (score 1):

The following should work as a regex solution:

```
/^\d{1,3}(\.?\d{3})?(,\d{0,2})?$/
```

Note that I made the thousands separator optional, if you want it to be mandatory just remove the `?` at the end of `\.?`.

Answer (score -1):

See [`number_format` on PHPJS](http://phpjs.org/functions/number_format:481) for a JavaScript port of PHP's `number_format`, that does exactly what you're looking for.