# Trying to add separators to numbers (the comma's and the .)

Tags: javascript, regex

So far I have:

```
var addSeparators = function (input, thousandSep, fractionSep) {
  if (!input) {
    return '';
  }
  return (input + '').replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+$)/g, '$1' + thousandSep);
};
```

If I call `addSeparators('1000', ',', '.');` I get `1,000` back.

If I call `addSeparators('1000.0234', ',', '.');` I get `1000.0,234` back but I would like `1,000.0234`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript or Notepad++ regular expression to add thousands separator to arbitrary text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18273464/javascript-or-notepad-regular-expression-to-add-thousands-separator-to-arbitra), also of [Thousand separator in javascript using regular expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12677766/thousand-separator-in-javascript-using-regular-expressions)

Answer (score 0):

```
  var addSeparators = function (input, thousandSep, fractionSep) {
  if (!input) {
    return '';
  }
  fraction=input.toString().split('.')[1];
  fraction=fraction?fractionSep+fraction:'';
  return parseInt(input).toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+$)/g,'$1'+thousandSep)+fraction;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function thousandSeparator(num) {
  return num.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}

thousandSeparator(1000.0234);
```